# In our direction Vs towards us

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Do both of the following sentences sound natural to you in AE:

> - They are shooting **in our direction**.
> - They are shooting **towards us**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dictionary provides a useful definition of *toward(s)*, and it appears that you have consulted your dictionary here. In natural speech (particularly when being targeted by a shooter!) you would almost never hear either of your alternative constructions. Instead, you would almost always hear:

> They're shooting **at** us!

However, both of your examples are equivalent in meaning, and they do sound "natural" to a native speaker.